# Find with like condition in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am having following array and I want to use search and sort.Search and sort are like sorting which we do with MySQL "LIKE" condition but in array not in database.

```
Array
(
    [4] => Varun Kumar
    [14] => Jason Ince
)
```

Like on typing 'jas' record with Jason Ince must come out of it with keys and values and rest of the record respectively.

Comment: Can you just loop through the array and do an strpos compare against each key:value pair?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
foreach($yourArr as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, $yourString) !== false) {
       //results here
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn RegEx.. they spoiled me! I totally forgot about `strpos()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($original_array, create_function($a, 'return stristr($a,"jas")!==false'));
```

OR, if you're using php 5.3+, syntax is:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($original_array, function($a){ return stristr($a,"jas")!==false });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function arraySearch( $array, $search ) { 
    foreach ($array as $a ) { 
        if(strstr( $a, $search)){ 
            echo $a;
        } 
    } 
return false; 
}
arraySearch(array("php","mysql","search"),"my"); // will return mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this way:

```
function check($yourString)
{
    foreach($yourArr as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $yourString) !== false)
            return strpos($value, $yourString);
    }
}
```

So that you can check the condition if not false.